# Как поменять дату создания мультимедиа?

Tags: cmd, bat, powershell, mp4

В папке несколько .mp4 файлов.

Я накидал PowerShell скрипт который меняет **дату создания файла** в зависимости от имени файла.

В PowerShell за это отвечает: **.CreationTime**
Но как поменять  **дату создания мультимедиа** (см. скрин, выделил красн)?

Можно ли это менять с помощью PS, так как дата должна быть в зависимости от имени файла?

**Скрин:**

[image]

**Скрипт (PS-скрипт запуск из батника):**

```html
@echo off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -command "dir C:\Users\home64\Downloads\1a -file | sort -property name -Descending | foreach {$i=0} {$_.CreationTime = (Get-Date).AddDays($i); $i++}"

pause
```

Comment: Это метаданные в самом файле. Для их редактирования потребуется соответствующая утилита, например mp4box

Comment: Если хочется именно через powershell, можно подключить стороннюю библиотеку, например, TagLib. Тогда вам будут доступны теги для фото и видео.